# Bind selected XML Content to Textbox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox

An XML file should be opened and the elements should be displayed in a `ListBox` where single elements can be selected. The selected elements should be displayed in a `TextBox` where they can be changed.

I managed to open and display the XML file in the `ListBox`. But how can I manage to display the selected XML content in the 2 `TextBox`es?

Here is the content of the XML file.

```
<Inventory xmlns="">
    <Books>
        <Book ISBN="0-7356-0562-9" Stock="in" Number="9">
            <Title>XML in Action</Title>
            <Summary>XML Web Technology</Summary>
        </Book>
        <Book ISBN="0-7356-1370-2" Stock="in" Number="8">
            <Title>Programming Microsoft Windows With C#</Title>
            <Summary>C# Programming using the .NET Framework</Summary>
        </Book>
        <Book ISBN="0-7356-1288-9" Stock="out" Number="7">
            <Title>Inside C#</Title>
            <Summary>C# Language Programming</Summary>
        </Book>
        <Book ISBN="0-7356-1377-X" Stock="in" Number="5">
            <Title>Introducing Microsoft .NET</Title>
            <Summary>Overview of .NET Technology</Summary>
        </Book>
        <Book ISBN="0-7356-1448-2" Stock="out" Number="4">
            <Title>Microsoft C# Language Specifications</Title>
            <Summary>The C# language definition</Summary>
        </Book>
    </Books>
</Inventory>
```

And here is the content of MainWindow.xaml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Window
    x:Class="XML_View_Edit.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="500"
    Height="200">
    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="InventoryData"
                         XPath="Inventory/Books"
                         Source="Data.xml"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition
                Height="100" />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox
            Grid.Row="0"
            Name="listBox1" >
            <ListBox.ItemsSource>
                <Binding Source="{StaticResource InventoryData}" XPath="Book"/>
            </ListBox.ItemsSource>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text = "{Binding XPath=Title}" />
                        <TextBlock Text= " - " />
                        <TextBlock Text = "{Binding XPath=Summary}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
        <Grid
            Grid.Row="1"
             DataContext="listBox1.SelectedItem">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition
                    Width="70" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Label
                Content="Title"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Name="label_title" />
            <Label
                Content="Summary"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Name="label_summary" />
            <TextBox
                Grid.Column="1"
                Name="textbox_title"
                Grid.Row="0" />
            <TextBox
                Grid.Column="1"
                Name="textbox_summary"
                Grid.Row="1" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The Title and Summary of the selected Book should be displayed in the 2 `TextBox`es, where the user can change each value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roughly:

- place the 2 `TextBox`es on a Container `C1`
- Bind `C1.DataContext` to `ListBox1.SelectedItem`

And I'm not sure what results `XPath="*"` in the `ListBox1` binding wil give. You probably want something like:

```
<Binding Source="{StaticResource InventoryData}" XPath="@ISBN"/>
```

---

#### Edit

You need to actually bind the `TextBox` elements:

```
      <TextBox
            Grid.Column="1"
            Name="textbox_title"
            Text = "{Binding XPath=Title}"   <!-- this -->
            Grid.Row="0" />
        <TextBox
            Grid.Column="1"
            Name="textbox_summary"
            Text = "{Binding XPath=Summary}"   <!-- and this -->
            Grid.Row="1" />
```

Give that a try.

#### Edit 2:

And let's fix the binding of the inner Grid:

```
  DataContext="{Binding ElementName=listBox1, Path=SelectedItem}"
```

Comment: The two textboxes are in a <Grid DataContext="listBox1.SelectedItem"></Grid> element. Could you please add some code snippet for explanation.

Comment: You should have posted that. What is and what is not working then?

Comment: Post the XAML for the boxes. And for the Grid.

Comment: <Grid
   DataContext="listBox1.SelectedItem">
   <Label
    Content="Title"
    Grid.Row="0"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Name="label_name" />
   <Label
    Content="Summary"
    Grid.Row="1"
    Grid.Column="0"
    Name="label_text" />
   <TextBox
    Grid.Column="1"
    Name="textBox_title"
    Grid.Row="0" >
   </TextBox>
   <TextBox
    Grid.Column="1"
    Name="textBox_summary"
    Grid.Row="1" />
  </Grid>

Comment: sorry ... posting code in comments isn't really good. I've uploaded some codesnippet: http://codeviewer.org/view/code:2e50

Comment: I've now corrected indentation http://codeviewer.org/view/code:2e52 (and this is the whole code of the Grid element)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22675/discussion-between-wewa-and-henk-holterman)

Comment: You should add the XAML for the grid and the boxes and post it here on SO.

Comment: I've now edited my question. There is now displayed the whole content of the file MainWindow.xaml

Comment: Much better. I'll extend my answer.

Comment: Really nice from you. :D After adding the text binding, I get following binding error. `System.Windows.Data Error: 44 : BindingExpression with XPath cannot bind to non-XML object.; XPath='Title' BindingExpression:Path=/InnerText; DataItem='String' (HashCode=-525142098); target element is 'TextBox' (Name='textbox_title'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') listBox1.SelectedItem` (same for summary)

Comment: Perfect :D - I can also change the text (in the textbox) and it's changed in the listBox to. But how to I manage that the changes are stored in the XML file? (Or should I make a new question for that?)

Comment: Yes, make it a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<ListBox
    Grid.Row="0"
    Name="listBox1" >
    <ListBox.ItemsSource>
        <Binding Source="{StaticResource InventoryData}" XPath="*"/>
</ListBox.ItemsSource>
 <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <TextBlock Text = "{Binding XPath=Title}">
      <TextBlock Text = "{Binding XPath=Summary}">
    </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: I've tried your code. But how/where these TextBlocks displayed?

Comment: Seems '*' is not working, Where -> it is set as datatemplete. Why not displaying -> because XPath=* is not working. Can you try XPath="Book" instead of XPath="*"

Comment: I'Ve changed to XPath="Book" but nothing is displayed in the textboxes

Comment: can you show binding errors from output window. [How to enable binding error tracing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsldesigner/archive/2010/06/30/debugging-data-bindings-in-a-wpf-or-silverlight-application.aspx)

Comment: There aren't any errors displayed, but here you can see the whole code. Maybe you can find the mistake there. http://codeviewer.org/view/code:2e53

Comment: can you remove XPath="Book" all together and try. If that does not work, Try to change `XPath=Title` to `XPath=Book/Title` (and keep trying with different format of Book/Title

Comment: I think we are talking at cross purposes. Displaying the XML content in listBox1 works fine with the code in the link from my comment above. But how do I manage to display/bind the Title and Summary of the selected book in the two according textboxes?